# What criteria is used to sort the outliner when "Sort Alphabetically" is off?

Tags: outliner

What Criteria is used to sort the outliner when "Sort Alphabetically" is off? The order definitely changes when I toggle that setting, but I can't tell what the order is changing to.

Comment: I may guess they are "by date". They are shown in the oreder they has been stored. On the top the most recently added object to the scene and in the bottom the first object ever created. Isn't for you the same? Did you tried with a simple test file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the default *All Scenes* filter and excluding *remapping users*, it becomes sorted top-down by ***last added***. This is somewhat obvious if you disable the option and just add objects to the scene. No object type takes precedence. To make sure, also checked the [source](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/d7f55c4ff58f87b80f0ce2fa43ce2f7cd2b72675/source/blender/editors/space_outliner/outliner_tree.c#L1493) and it seems to do just that.